# How to calculate standard dev multiplier when duplicating same dataset when you only know standard dev, average and number of observations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a dataset and I know the number of observations in it, the average of all the values in it and the standard deviation of all those values.

Using only the above information, I want to be able to figure out the standard deviation of this same data if I duplicate it once or twice or more.

What I know is that after I duplicate my dataset once the multiplier to get from my original standard deviation to the one after I duplicate the dataset is the same regardless of the values in that dataset.

So if I have two data points, it doesn't matter what the values are for those data points: the multiplier to get from the original standard deviation (when i have just two data points) to the one after I duplicate the dataset (when I have four datapoints) is the same.

However, this multiplier changes when the number of observations in the original dataset changes. For example, the multiplier when I originally have 2 data points (and go to 4) is different than when I originally have 3 (and go to 6).

Here's a couple of examples of a dummy dataset to illustrate what I mean.

If I originally have $2$ data points:
[image: If I originally have 2 data points]

If I originally have $3$ data points:
[image: If I originally have 3 data points]

So, is there a way to figure out what the standard deviation would be after I duplicated my original dataset if I only knew the number of observations, the average and the standard deviation of my original dataset?

So, for example, if the values in my dataset have an avg of 32 and a stdev of 12.3 and 100 observations, then what would I need to multiply the stdev by to know what it would be after I duplicate the dataset and there's now 200 observations? And what would I need to multiply the stdev by if I had 101 observations and after duplicated had 202 observations, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:algebra-precalculus]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$.

Suppose there are initially $n$ data points.

If you duplicate your data $m$ times, the sample mean remains the same.

The new standard deviation is now

$$\sqrt{\frac{m\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{nm-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{m(n-1)}{mn-1}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$$

The multiplier is $\sqrt{\frac{m(n-1)}{mn-1}}$.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Do you recommend any resource for algebra?

Comment: Most texts are fine. Find one with many practices. The key is to have more practices. :)